# Dropbox syncing RTF-editor for iPad with color markup possibilities

Tags: ipad, ios, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an app for iPad in which you can:

1. Sync with dropbox
2. Save and edit RTF-files
3. Color markup text (in addition to making text bold, change fontsize, et cetera)

Comment: I am looking for the same. It would already help if there was a converter between RTF and Pages, so that I could convert my existing RTFs to .pages files on the iPhone/iPad, edit them in Pages, then convert them back to RTF and store them again in my Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like [Textastic](http://www.textasticapp.com), which can sync with Dropbox, FTP, SFTP, etc and does code highlighting for code & markup and has a customizable keyboard area.